PowerShell and escape characters
While messing with a couple of kubectl commands in Windows PowerShell, I've encountered this error:

Error from server (BadRequest): invalid character '\' looking for beginning of object key string
Error from server (NotFound): serviceaccounts "imagePullSecrets\: [{\name\: \gwregistry\}]}" not found

It is clearly an escape character problem, but I can't figure out what the problem really is.
The command is the following:
kubectl -n opmtotoholding patch serviceaccount default -p "{\"imagePullSecrets\": [{\"name\": \"gwregistry\"}]}"

Tried to change the outer quote from double to single but I get the same error.
Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Try PowerShell's stop-parsing token --% kubectl --% -n opmtotoholding patch serviceaccount default -p "{\"imagePullSecrets\": [{\"name\": \"gwregistry\"}]}"

To embed a " inside a PowerShell "..." string, you must escape it as \"(or""); inside '...', no escaping is needed. When calling _external programs_ from _Windows PowerShell_ and PowerShell (Core) _v7.2 or lower_ - you must unfortunately _additionally_ escape (the possibly already escaped-for-PowerShell) embedded "chars. with ``\`` (which itself has _no_ special meaning in PowerShell), e.g.,foo.exe "{ \"bar\\": 42 }"orfoo.exe '{ "bar": 42 }'`. See the linked duplicate for details.

To escape a " in a double-quoted string literal, either double it "" or escape it using a backtick `":
... -p "{""imagePullSecrets"": [{""name"": ""gwregistry""}]}"
# or
... -p "{`"imagePullSecrets`": [{`"name`": `"gwregistry`"}]}"

Since you're not interpolating any variable expressions in the string, you could also use a verbatim string literal - simply change the enclosing " to single-quotes ':
... -p '{"imagePullSecrets": [{"name": "gwregistry"}]}'

Or, finally, you could construct the json document as a custom object/hashtable and convert that to JSON before passing as an argument to kubectl:
$kubeArg = @{
  imagePullSecrets = @(
    @{
        name = 'gwregistry'
    }
  )
} |ConvertTo-Json -Compress

kubectl -n opmtotoholding patch serviceaccount default -p $kubeArg

